# What does "A Stitch In Crime" mean?

Tags: title, columbo

In the famous series *Columbo* there's an episode called **"A Stitch In Crime"** (Season 2, Episode 6). Now, I'm trying to understand the meaning of this title. Is there any connection to the idiom *"a stitch in time saves nine"*?

Comment: Isaac Asimov wrote a humorous science fiction story where a criminal named Stein used a time machine to travel into the future when the statute of limitations for his crime was over.  The Judge  ruled that Stein could no be tried, saying "A niche in time saves Stein".

Comment: _A niche in time?_ I don't quite get the meaning of this expression either.

Comment: A niche is like a comfortable and secure place, like the right place for you (or your business sometimes).  In Asimov's very funny sentence, it means that the killer had found the perfect place in (a) time(frame) to kill and not be guilty. As non-native speaker, I even hear a pun with "saves  Stein" -> "saves time"

Comment: @M.A.Golding: thanks for helping Asimov make me a laughable sunday morning :)

Comment: @JContantine, note that 'niche' is pronounced 'nitch' in American English.  The phrase is a spoonerism when said aloud: stitch/nine  becomes nitch/Stein.  The story's title was 'A Loint of Paw'.

Comment: When I first heard the phrase "a stitch in time", I thought it was literally a stitch located in time. As in two locations in spacetime were stitched together. Like "a wrinkle in time", except a stitch rather than a wrinkle.

Comment: @M.A.Golding I would think that traveling through time would take quite a toll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The episode is about a surgeon killing his partner by using the wrong medical device. Mayfield performs the surgery using non-permanent sutures, that will kill his patient when it dissolves in his body. He had colored the thread to make it look like permanent one.

As a non-native English speaking folk, it seems like a eye-catching play on words/meanings because it evokes the idea of sutures (stitches) and time needed to dissolve them in order to kill.

As "*a stitch in time saves nine*" can be translated as "*it's better to prevent than cure*", we have all possible meanings and puns related to a scenario involving killing with medical methods.

Answer (score 2):

Having no specific recollection of the episode in question, perhaps, if you do have recollection, you can compare against this notion:

It clearly plays on the stitch in time axiom as a clever title gimmick to get viewer attention: it got yours, after all. But as an author of books, I do exactly the same with chapter titles as often as possible, and also as staff writer for Eternal Affairs, with similar plays on words within dialog. I'll preface the final attempt at actual answer to your question with an example from the TOC of Volume I of my Fatal Rebirth Book series (even that title follows in the mold), because it examples visibly. Below are the Chapter names, and sub-chapter headings (image):

[image]

You can see that in my case, there is a kind of sequential or other narrative obtained just from the titles... not applicable to Columbo, but important in terms of curiosity generation. The book(s) recount the history of America's dark bumps in the night from 1947 through 9-11 (which it predicted) and into today's and tomorrow's future, with way more accuracy than I would have liked (i.e., COVID, Great Reset, Financial ruin of the economy, etc.) all based on something called the Unified Conspiracy Theory (quite accurate, and based in part on a patent application I wrote for a political scientist to predict future political evolutions of hegemonic states). It is a fictional storyline as a framework for a kind of mockumentary presentation of facts, supported with 1500 factual footnotes and an Appendix larger than some books, between the four volumes.

So the challenge... as does apply to Columbo, is to tie the titles to aspects within the story line (Columbo plot), and to provide a challenge for the reader (viewer) to so discover, and ideally (book), to mirror the greater theme of (a) the Chapter, and (b) the book title. In Chapter one, for instance, Each sub title is discovered to clearly identify or relates to the characteristics of a key character introduced into the story line. As it happens, the Pen, for instance, is actually me, as much of what appears in the book (and for the matter, accounts for the reason of its existence), is based on personal James Bondian experiences. It was my codename in secretive communications with intelligence community types and other parties. The other chapters have differing thematics to discover.

AS TO COLUMBO, based on my own uses, I'm going to presume that within the script, the criminal's undoing has to do with the timing of a sequence of events relating to the crime and their discovery, vs. the time component of suspect testimony or derived clues (i.e., broken clock, etc.). I would not be surprised, recalling the cleverness of show writers (great detective series), if it was not multi-layered... such that there were multiple suspects eliminated one by one due elements tied to time.

In a single hour, it would be difficult to do that with nine suspects, but perhaps nine different events, or nine clues... something in the episode, I'm thinking, involved nine... if not simply the time of the murder or the time on the clock for the clue that stitched the killers fate. I'd bank on a Grandfather or chiming clock in there, somewhere... or something to do with sewing, or both.

I'd be very curious as to if this was this case, if you are able to confirm or deny.